# Setting different font sizes for TextBlock items in ListView with state triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

Developing a Windows 10 Universal App, I can't get a visual state trigger to change the font size of a TextBlock that is used in an ItemTemplate for a ListView. I'm trying to use the trigger as for any other element, but it won't change the font size when I resize the window. Here are the main pieces of code of my xaml page:

Item template:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PresentationItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PresentationListViewItemTextBlock"
                       x:Uid="PresentationListViewItemTextBlock"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Visual state triggers:

```
<VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="{StaticResource Height1}" 
                             MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource Width1}"/>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="PresentationListViewItemTextBlock.FontSize" Value="40"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>

    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource Width2}"
                             MinWindowHeight="{StaticResource Height2}"/>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="PresentationListViewItemTextBlock.FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Definition of ListView in page:

```
<ListView x:Name="AvailablePresentationsListView"
          x:Uid="AvailablePresentationsListView"
          DataContext="{Binding}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PresentationCollection}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PresentationItemTemplate}"/>
```

My guess is that there is a problem with setting a state trigger on a property of a template item. How can I manage to set different font sizes to my ListView TextBlock items when I resize my screen, then? Thanks.

Comment: Tip: Do not use x:Uid in a DataTemplate, the key has to be unique on your page. Used in a DataTemplate it's used in every item in your ListView.

Comment: How do your states get called? I see no names or GoToState's. Where do these VisualStates live? In the ListView template or within the DataTemplate? Also WPF isn't UWP, you may need an actual storyboard to change the property instead of flopping your setter in like you might on a WPF style trigger. I'd assume your problem will start with the first question and end in the last one.